# How to estimate latent variable in Tobit Model

Tags: latent-variable, tobit-regression

I have a Tobit model of the form:

Yi* = latent variable;
Yi = censored (observable) variable;

Yi* = β0 + β1*Xi + ϵ

where **ϵ** is a random variable normally distributed with **mean of zero** and variance of **σ2**. To facilitate the notation I will use **μi = β0 + β1*Xi**.

The correlation between the Yi and Yi* can be written as:

Yi = 1, if Yi* >= 1;

Yi = Yi*, if 0 < Yi* < 1;

So the latent variable is unknown when Yi = 1 and I would like to estimate it. I think point estimates for the latent variable can be calculated using the conditional mean, like: E[Yi*|Yi=1,μi,σ].

But, please, could someone help me with the exact formula to do this?

**Edit:** In R, I'm using the AER package to calculate the tobit model, the scale parameter σ and the fitted values (μi)

```
tobit.model <- tobit(Y ~ X, right = 1)

sigma <- tobit.model$scale

ui <- fitted(tobit.model)
```

Comment: Hi Dave. Welcome to CV. I know you are new. But you can use the facility of the site being MathJax enabled. For a quick intro, check [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: thanks for the tip, mate!

Comment: When you say you're looking for "the exact formula to do this," are you referring to the mathematical details of your [right-censored tobit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83059), or are you asking for the R code?